# How to show that $a$ can be divided by $6$ if and only if it can be divided by both $2$ and $3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that for: $a \in\mathbb Z$, $a$ is divisible by 2 and $a$ is divisible by 3 if and only if $a$ is divisible by 6.

EDIT: Sorry, I wasn't aware of how exactly this site worked. This is pretty much a question from my Discrete Math course that I was having a little trouble understanding. Apologies for not being clear about the background and only posting a question with no context.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Can you prove one of the directions?

Comment: The question was posted 23 minutes ago, two people asked questions and we already want to close it without giving the OP an opportunity to respond?

Comment: Point of information: The closure vote was there even before I left my comment.

Comment: The reason that I voted to close is that this question as it is currently worded lacks crucial elements of good questions on this site: background information about where the question was encountered and a description of what the asker had tried before asking it. I would vote to reopen if this information was added.

Comment: @Michael: thanks for the edit; I voted to reopen. Can you already prove half of it, namely that a number divisible by 6 is divisible by 2 and by 3? Separately, do you know at this point in the class that each positive natural number factors uniquely as a product of primes?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** We write $a\mid b$ for "$a$ divides $b$".

1. If $p$ is a prime number and $p\mid a\cdot b$ then either $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$;
2. if $x\mid y$ and $y\mid z$ then $x\mid z$ as well.
3. $2$ and $3$ are prime numbers; $6=2\cdot 3$.

Comment: Nice, Asaf + 1 ;-)

Comment: I didn't even remember writing this answer... :|

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\ \dfrac{a}6\, =\, \dfrac{a}2\, -\, \dfrac{a} 3$

Comment: While correct, it's not clear why $\frac a2$ and $\frac a3$ are integers. We can't conclude that if the difference is an integer then the rational numbers are integers as well.

Comment: @Asaf $ $ They are integers by hypothesis, i.e. if $\ 2,3\mid a\ $ then $\ a/2,\ a/3\ $ are integers, thus so is their difference $\ a/6,\ $ i.e. $\ 6\mid a.\ $

Comment: Yes, that is one direction, but what about the other?

Comment: @Asaf $ $ The other direction is clear: $ $ if $\ 2\cdot 3\mid a\ $ then $\ 2,3\mid a.\ $

Comment: I blame the fact that I slept for three hours in the morning, spent two hours commuting to the university, met two students, gave a lecture, two hours back home, and still haven't had any sleep! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

$\Rightarrow$

Assume a is divisible by $2$ and $3$. By Euclid's algorithm

$$
a=6q+r
$$

where $0\le |r|\le 5$

But $r=a-6q$ and since each of $6$ and $a$ are divisible by both $2$ and $3$, $r$ is divisible by both $2$ and $3$ and so must be $0$.

Therefore, $a$ is divisible by $6$.

$\Leftarrow$

If $a$ is divisible by $6$ then $a=6n$ for some $n$ so $$a=6n=2(3n) = 3(2n)$$

, therefore $a$ is divisible by both $2$ and $3$.

Comment: I would use something like your last line of equations for the => direction: $$a=2m=3n$$ so $3|m, 2|n$ ...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:  $(2)(3) = 6$

LCM of 2 and 3 is 6.

This doesn't act as a proof, but it should help you make sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

If $(p,q)=1$, then there exist $u,v$ such that $up+vq=1$. If we now suppose that $p$ and $q$ divide $a$, then we may write $ps=a=qt$. Multiplying the equation $up+vq=1$ by $a$ we obtain $upa+vqa=a$ or $upqt+vqps=a$. Hence $pq$ divides $a$.
Clearly if we can $a$ by $pq$ then we can divide $a$ by $p$ and $q$.